# SQL Datetime conversion from an Adobe export

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, adobe-analytics

I am really hoping someone will either be able to answer this in seconds or possibly someone has done this already with Adobe Data warehouse and SQL.

We have a feed that has a date column however the date is in the following format:

"MONTH DD, YYYY, 'Hour' H"
so for example:
"June 4, 2017, Hour 8"
or
"October 21, 2016, Hour 23"

I am looking for a simple one liner that can convert this into a more date time friendly format such as the following:

"YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS"
such as
"20170604 08:00:00"
or
"20161021 23:00:00"

I would be very grateful for any help. 
Thanks

Comment: The simple thing is to *not* export data in such an unusual format. Use ISO8601.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('June 4, 2017, Hour 8')
,('October 21, 2016, Hour 23')

Select *
      ,Convert(datetime,replace(SomeCol,', Hour','' )+':00:00' )
 from @YourTable
```

If 2012+, I would recommend Try_Convert()... just in case you have unexpected values.

Returns

```
SomeCol                    (No column name)
June 4, 2017, Hour 8        2017-06-04 08:00:00.000
October 21, 2016, Hour 23   2016-10-21 23:00:00.000
```

**Panagiotis Kanavos has a valid point**

```
Parse(replace(SomeCol,', Hour','' )+':00:00' as datetime using 'en-US')
```

Comment: That's a localized conversion. Better use `PARSE(... as DATETIME USING 'en-US')`